# Filling different subjects for each student based on its class level

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I'm asking for an idea to move on my database. My database is about students marks management. I have three class levels of students (Class A, Class B, Class C), where each class has its own subjects which illustrated below:

```
Class A:               Class B:              Class C:
Subject1               Subject4              Subject7              
Subject2               Subject5              Subject8
Subject3               Subject6              Subject9
```

Now. lets present my tables. I have two tables linked (one to many) by the studentID, the first one is "AllStudents":

```
Table: AllStudents
StudentsID       StudentsNmae        ClassName
```

And the second table is "StudentsMarks"

```
Table: StudentsMarks
ID       StudentsID        SubjectName   Mark1    Mark2     Mark3
```

So, for each student entered, the corresponding subjects should be listed in the third column (SubjectName) of the StudentsMarks table.  For example,

```
StudentsID       StudentsNmae        ClassName
 1                 Alex              Class A

          ID       StudentsID        SubjectName   Mark1    Mark2     Mark3
           1           1             Subject1
           2           1             Subject2
           3           1             Subject3                  

StudentsID       StudentsNmae        ClassName
 2                 Jimes              Class B

          ID       StudentsID        SubjectName   Mark1    Mark2     Mark3
           4           2             Subject4
           5           2             Subject5
           6           2             Subject6
```

And so on for the rest of entries. Any idea or approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Won't students progress through class levels? Will this db contain multi-year records? Including this value in Students table will require changing it each year for every student. Perhaps you need a separate table for StudentRegistration that includes StudentID, Year, ClassLevel.

Have a table that associates subjects with class level. That last example looks like report output. Include the ClassSubjects table in report RecordSource so the class level is available to sort records. This will also be useful to create cascading comboboxes so that subjects available for selection for a student can be restricted to those associated with the class level student is currently registered in.

Programmatically adding a set of records can get complicated and there is more than one way. One approach involves an SQL INSERT action using the suggested ClassSubjects table and concatenates values selected from comboboxes on a form.

```
CurrentDb.Execute  "INSERT INTO StudentsMarks(StudentID, SubjectID) SELECT " & Me.cbxStudentID & " AS StuID, SubjectID FROM ClassSubjects WHERE ClassID = " & Me.cbxClassID
```

This is very simplistic example and doesn't prevent insert of duplicate records. That's where code can get complicated, validating data. This is not conventional db design and will require learning fairly advanced VBA and SQL. Do research and learn, lots of examples out there. When you have some code that has an issue, post it for analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, it is one year database. the last example is an illustration  of the relational records. i.e., when the new student entered, then the studentMarks will be generated. I just want the subjects entered automatically not by the user.

Comment: A table would not be structured like that. It looks like report output. You want to create StudentsMarks records before marks are even available for input? Will require VBA code to create records.

Comment: StudentsMarks would be created as a sub table for each student!!!they are linked by ID as a one to many relationship. I just want when new student is recorded, the the third column  of StudentsMarks table ( which is refered to the SubjectName) is filled by the corresponding class

Comment: What do you mean by 'a sub table for each student' - should not be a table for each student. Again, require VBA code to automate creating records.

Comment: Could you provide some examples how to automate in vba? assuming  that  the AllStudents is the record source of the main form and StudentsMarks  is the record source of the subform

Comment: See revised Answer above.